# How to change default ASR (Automated Speech Recognition) when making tensoflow lite model?

Tags: audio, classification, speech-recognition, tensorflow-lite

I am creating an tensoflow lite model for audio classification and it is using default ASR so I want to change it, because if it uses default ASR, I can't use any other app that has any sort of audio feature for example I can't use whatsapp voice message feature.

Comment: Hi Faizan, could you provide more detail? What's the "default ASR"? Are you referring to an example on the TensorFlow Lite website? It's hard to help without more information

Comment: Default asr in android is ASR which uses default microphone for any activity for example when we send audio chat and it uses default microphone(ASR).

Comment: Default asr in android is ASR which uses default microphone for any activity for example when we send audio chat and it uses default microphone(ASR). So When making tensorflow lite model for speech recognition/audio classification, it also uses default ASR, and if I run this model on background services. I can't send audio message on whats app. So I was thinking is there anyway to change ASR in tensorflow. https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/tutorials/model_maker_speech_recognition